# CSS positioning of fixed social button div relative to another div or container

Tags: css, positioning, fixed

Honestly, before this problem I kinda thought that I actually knew something about css positioning, but it looks that I do not.

Here is what I have, I need to position the social buttons div on the left of the container and make it fixed so it does not move, but only until the bottom of that div is lined up with the bottom of the container in which it was positioned then it will need to scroll further. I do not know if I am explaining my self so that everyone can understand what I mean here so please take a look at the following [example](http://www.ehow.com/info_8493383_tips-keeping-christmas-tree-alive.html)

The div with all facebook, twitter, G+ and print buttons is scrollable until it is aprox. 10px below the top of the browser, then it stops and continues to scroll only after the bottom of it is lined up with the container that it is placed in to.

Please help, I am kinda stack with it

Comment: You can't do it with pure CSS. You need to use javascript.

Comment: I though so too, but was not sure. Any idea on where I can find an examples or tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a CSS question unless you're willing to make-do with `position: sticky`, which probably isn't what you're looking for. (Reading about it [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit))

If you're looking for a jQuery solution, then you could use [ScrollFollow](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/), where you can specify a container parent for the fixed-scrolling item.